# scala enumeratee to get the length

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10, scala-2.8

I have a Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]] with scala

```
class AccessLog extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(next: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    lazy val processor: RequestStatsProcessor = RequestStatsProcessor.getInstance
    def apply(rh: RequestHeader) = {
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis
      def writeableEnumeratee[A](writeable: Writeable[A]): Enumeratee[A, Array[Byte]] = Enumeratee.map(a => writeable.transform(a))
      var size: Long = 0;
      def logTime(response: PlainResult): Result = response match {
        case simple @ SimpleResult(header, body) => {
          val time = System.currentTimeMillis - start

          val en = Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]] { item =>
            size = size + item.length
            var requestInfo: RequestInfo = new RequestInfo(start, rh, response, size)
            processor.setRequest(requestInfo)
            processor.process
            item
          }
          SimpleResult(header, body &> writeableEnumeratee(simple.writeable) &> en)
        }
        case _ => response
      }
      next(rh).map {
        case plain: PlainResult => logTime(plain)
        case async: AsyncResult => async.transform(logTime)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if I write like this, I'll get each length of the Array[Byte] but not total size in the map?

How can I do to get the total length?

Comment: I have a question regarding your code... what are `size` and `a`? where do they come from and what are their purpose? I'm asking because they seemingly appear out of nowhere, as they aren't declared within the scope of your map

Comment: @Electric Coffee hi  I update my question. Would you please see the updated post again?

Comment: I still can't find where `a` is declared

Comment: @Electric Coffee I changed the a to item, so you can find it easier. please help

Comment: This question would benefit a lot from some minimization—it's pretty hard to tell what you're asking.